# inline jquery data assignment

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-data

I've seen some data accessed in a javascript function like this:

```
$(this).data('js');
```

In the html, the data is assigned like this.

```
<li data-js="m">
    <a href="#">Male</a>
</li>
<li data-js="f">
    <a href="#">Female</a>
</li>
```

I've just not seen this done before. And I don't really know what to call it to search for it.  Inline jquery data assignment? Is it good practice? Well supported? What's it called? Thanks!

Comment: They're called `data` attributes. They are part of the HTML5 specification.

Comment: This is what you need [http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-*-attributes](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-*-attributes)

Comment: @thomas The end of using `rel` and `class` attributes to handle data are over! Now we can use `data` attributes to store data related to elements.

Answer (score 2):

This is a simple [jQuery method](http://api.jquery.com/data/#data2) that takes advantage of **[HTML5 Custom Data Attribute](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/dom.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-%2a-attributes)** feature:

> A custom data attribute is an attribute in no namespace whose name starts with the string "data-", has at least one character after the hyphen, is XML-compatible, and contains no uppercase ASCII letters.
>   Custom data attributes are intended to store custom data private to the page or application, for which there are no more appropriate attributes or elements.

In your example, the `$(this).data('js');` code will either return "m" or "f" depending on whether `this` refers to the first or second `li`.

Here are some relevant articles:

- http://html5doctor.com/html5-custom-data-attributes/
- http://ejohn.org/blog/html-5-data-attributes/ (This one is linked from the jQuery page above)

Answer (score 1):

the jQuery function is documented here http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/

and this has a good explanation of the html5 data attribute 
http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/htmlcss-tutorials/all-you-need-to-know-about-the-html5-data-attribute/

Answer (score -1):

Have you read the jQuery documentation? I think that will give you enough information on its usage and purpose http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/